# Is "turned into X for a Y duration" grammatically and semantically correct?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Is "turned into X for a Y duration" grammatically and semantically correct? It doesn't sound like something that sounds semantically correct, because the process of turning into something is instantaneous. It's implied that he reverts back after Y duration. However, it's semantically incorrect and imprecise, because the process of reverting back is not explicitly said.

For example:

> He turned into a monster for an entire week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if something does not sound correct, you should not use it. Even if technically the sentence is correct, if it feels uncomfortable when you read it, no doubt it will also feel wrong to any other recipient.
Try making two sentences **He turned into a monster.  For an entire week he….** Or alternatively **He became a monster for the entire week**.